# getting no result in terminal window

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have just started coding in C++ and I am using codeblocks. My build log is giving me 0 errors and 0 warning but I do not know why when I run it, it is giving me no result in the terminal.
Terminal Window Result:

> Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 1.252 s
> Press any key to continue.

my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<math.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    int a[n];
    for(int i = 0; i <n ; i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    const int N = pow(10, 6);
    int idx[N];
    for(int i = 0; i< N; i++){
        idx[i] = -1;
    }

    int minidx = INT_MAX;

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        if(idx[a[i]] != -1){
            minidx = min(minidx, idx[a[i]]);
        }
        else{
            idx[a[i]] = i;
        }
    }
    if (minidx == INT_MAX){
        cout<<"-1"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<minidx+1<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me in finding my mistake in the code.

Comment: When using C++, stick to C++ provided headers. Use `<cmath>` over `<math.h>`. Also, indentation helps.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of those non-standard variable-length arrays (whose size is most likely the source of your problems).

Comment: 1) "_My build log is giving me 0 errors and 0 warning_" That is very low bar at judging code quality. 2) If I remember correctly `0xC00000FD` means "Stack Overflow". 3) `int a[n];` where `n` is not known at compile time is non-standard C++. Which, on compilers that support VLAs, due to an extension, might cause stack overflow for sufficiently large values of `n`.

Comment: I believe the problem is the declaration of an array of size `1e6` in main(). Either make it global or use a standard container. VLAs are an extension provided by compilers. Don't use them.

Comment: Can confirm that irrespective of the size you enter at runtime of array `a` as size `n`, the crash will definitely be caused by the other array `idx [N]` where `N=1e6`. You can't declare an array that size in a function simply because of stack overflow.

Comment: afaik `cin>>n; int a[n];` never was the intended use case for VLAs, also in C (where VLAs are coming from) there are other solutions to this.

Comment: For gcc you need to use the `-pedantic` flag to get warnings for non-standard extensions: https://godbolt.org/z/a6vdao add `-Werror` to make it impossible to miss important warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/qnP7jM (warnings are always important!)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```cpp
int n;
std::cin >> n;

int a [n];

for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    std::cin >> a [i];
}
```

is bad practice. Don't use VLAs whose size you don't know at compile time. Instead, if I guess correctly that this is some Competitive Programming problem, you'll probably know what the max size will be as stated in the problem. So, do it this way instead:

```cpp
int n;
std::cin >> n;

constexpr int max_size = 1000000;
int a [max_size];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> a [i];
}
```

However, even doing it this way will crash your program anyway. This is simply because of stack overflow when you declare an array that size inside a function. For slightly smaller sizes however, that would be okay. Just don't use VLAs the way you're using them.

One solution is to use a standard container like `std::vector` as the allocation takes place on the heap. Note that using `std::array` will crash too as the allocation is not on the heap.

Another solution is to make your array `a` global. This way you can increase to sizes well over `1e6`. Not really recommended though.

In your code above, irrespective of what the size `n` for array `a` is (even if it's a fairly small size to fit on the stack), your code will definitely crash when you declare the array `idx [1000000]`. Reason is the same, stack overflow.

Also, please post indented code and use good indentation practices.

Comment: "Don't use VLAs whose size you don't know at compile time" its a matter or wording, but you never know the size of a VLA at compile time, thats what makes it a VLA

Comment: @idclev463035818 Right, I messed up my wording a little bit. Anyways, my point was that you can't declare huge arrays inside a function as it would crash no matter what you did.

Comment: i didnt comment on your point, only on that sentence on VLAs which doesn't make sense

Comment: @idclev463035818 Off topic but I must say, you've got a nice `About Me` section.